# Extracting Json response using Json extractor on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, response, jsonpath, json-path-expression, json-extract

Is there's a way I could extract the highest id: "15" of bld-appliance-1 using Json Path expression. Currently if use this Json expression "[?(@.name == 'bld-appliance-1')]..id" it returns me 3 result. I'm also aware I could use Match No but my catch here is the response is **DYNAMIC** I don't know if the 1st, 2nd or 3rd and etc is the highest id upon invocation. Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Sample Response:

[{

```
    "id": "5",
    "name": "bld-appliance-1",
    "hostName": "bld-appliance-1"
},

{
    "id": "10",
    "name": "bld-appliance-1",
    "hostName": "bld-appliance-1"
},

{
    "id": "15",
    "name": "bld-appliance-1",
    "hostName": "bld-appliance-1"
},
{
    "id": "20",
    "name": "test-appliance-1",
    "hostName": "test-appliance-1"
}, {
    "id": "25",
    "name": "uat-appliance-1",
    "hostName": "uat-appliance-1"
}
```

]

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
def id = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).findAll {entry -> entry.name == 'bld-appliance-1'}.collect{entry -> entry.id as int}.max()
```

in case you need to store the result into a JMeter Variable you can add the next line:

```
vars.putObject('id', id)
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)